# How to retrieve files from VDI?

Tags: drivers, mount, graphics, virtualbox, data-recovery

I need to retrieve some files from an unbootable Ubuntu VM. The VM is installed into a VDI file.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Easy.

1. Spin up another VM and install Ubuntu into it
2. Attach the VDI file from your old VM to the new VM
3. Use Nautilus to browse the other drive and recover the files